# How to change password requirements in firebase

Tags: reactjs

I have a firebase CreateAccauntwithEmailandPassword and i want to make it so that the password has at least one uppercase letter and one number and isn't just 6 l's how can i do that also i want custom error messages. I am new to react and js as a whole.